# On Windows, adb connects to wrong port 5037 instead of 5555

Tags: windows, android-studio, adb

Debugging an Android App over WiFi. I am using [WiFi ADB App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) to prepare the Android Device for the connection over Wifi. All seems well on that end.

Next, I need to connect adb as follows:

```
adb connect 192.168.2.8:5555
```

Sometimes this works properly. But more often, I get the following message:

```
C:\> adb connect 192.168.2.8:5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.2.8:5555
```

Even though everything seems in order, I have learned that when I see this message, AndroidStudio (version 1.1.0) will not be able to find my AndroidDevice.

I am not the first to run into this, [this article](http://www.programering.com/a/MTNyUDMwATA.html) suggests a solution. This does not (or nearly never) work for me. However, interesting things do happen.

- When opening up Windows TaskManager, I can see **one** `adb.exe (32 bit)` background process. I kill it via `End task` button.
- Next, I execute the `adb connect 192.168.2.8:5555` command in Windows cmd shell. I briefly see **two** `adb.exe (32 bit)` background processes appear in TaskManager. After a second, one process disappears.
- In the cmd shell, I get the same stuff about starting on port 5037, which means that -again- AndroidStudio can not find my device.

It looks to me like two adb.exe processes are started up, that one locks port 5555, and that neither process give me a findable connection; not even after one of the processes has been (auto)terminated.

*How can I connect adb so that it actually starts on port 5555 and AndroidStudio can actually find my device?*

**update:**

1.) I misunderstood the message:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

This means that the daemon is not yet running *on the development machine*. (I understood this to be the target machine.) You will get this message if you issue `adb connect *.*.*.*` without AndroidStudio running (yet). On the development machine, it stars on port 5037.

Then, you get the message:

```
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 192.168.2.8:5555
```

It means that it is connected to port 5555 *on the target machine* (= your Android device).

2. It turned out, the above issue was caused by faulty hardware (WiFi adapter). So I was barking up the wrong tree; looking for a software solution.

Comment: At least read the tag wiki. Your title is completely wrong. Everything you describe is exactly how it is supposed to be (minus using some unnecessary app). Your "solution" (for non-existing problem) is the standard and documented way to connect to `adb` device over tcpip (i.e. wifi) without any 3rd party apps

Comment: What "tag wiki" are you talking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info the `5037` port is used for communication between the `adb client` and the `adb server`. which has nothing to do with the `5555` port the `adbd daemon` on the device is listening on

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, in the console, the solutions appears to be (?)

```
adb kill-server
SET ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=5555
adb connect 192.168.2.8:5555
```

AndroidStudio finds the device after the extra `adb tcpip 5555` statement.

**update:**

The above does not appear to be the solution, at least not in 100% of the cases. Still haven't found something that works and is reproducible...

Comment: All of Android Studio is not reproducible. Very buggy. Way still to go to reach Visual Studio Masterpiece.